# How to Use jQuery select() to select content of a div in a popup?

Tags: jquery, asp.net

Hi all i am working on jquery i need to  Use jQuery select() to select content of a div in a popup
i had written code in the html page it's working fine but when comes to poup it dosen't work

here i am calling a pop up in that pop up i have a div in that div  i have a button in that 
i am calling a callingmethod(); but i's not working

do i have to change anything in this code  please help to make it thanks in advance
here my code

```
<input type="button"  id="btncall" onclick="callingmethod('selectable');" value="c0py" />
```

text to be copy

```
<div id="selectable">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
             Quisque eu ante ac massa dignissim tempor id nec lectus. Vestibulum commodo purus 
             vel nisl vulputate ac porttitor erat luctus. </div>
```

here is a calling function

```
function callingmethod(containerid) {

             if (document.selection) {
                alert(1);
                var range = document.body.createTextRange();
                range.moveToElementText(document.getElementById(containerid));
                range.select();
            } else if (window.getSelection) {
                var range = document.createRange();
                range.selectNode(document.getElementById(containerid));
                window.getSelection().addRange(range);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have an element having an id of `selectable` anywhere in your code. And thus, are getting an error.

Add the following to your html file:

`<input type='text' id='selectable' />`

Type something into it. And press copy.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/xjF35/1/)**

Comment: thanks for reply the above code modified  i had tried you suggestion it's not working could you please check once

Comment: @Sadda-shutu You want, on click of `c0py` button, to select whole text of div, right ? http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/xjF35/1/

Comment: thanks for reply it's working jsfiddle when comes to pop up not working

Comment: @Sadda-shutu then please share your popup code also.